# How to plot array in ggplot2 together with texts in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been struggle a lot with this. So I'd appreciate if someone let me know the solution.

We can plot array by using this code :

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
qplot(seq_along(a), a)
```

We also can add labels on x-values as follows :

```
names(a) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
```

However, I could not find how to plot variables in array together with its name on x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scale_x_discrete.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
names(a) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
qplot(seq_along(a), a) + 
        scale_x_discrete(labels = names(a))
```

Comment: Or just qplot(names(a), a)